# Modifying a sunburst chart with % symbols and joint legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, pgf-pie

I copied a code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433848/is-there-a-way-to-make-sunburst-charts-multi-level-pie-charts-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) to make a sunburst chart, but I need to make 2 modifications that I haven't been able to work out:

1. is to add `%` into the text, and
2. is to create a joined legend for both pies in the figure.

When I tried to insert `\%` after the number in the following for example (`\%` is in bold)

```
\arctext[N1][firstgreen][15pt](1.5)(90)(-3.6){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| 1 26 **\%**};
```

the whole thing crashed.

If anybody could point out how I can make these 2 modifications that'd be super helpful.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{firstgreen}{HTML}{58D68D}
\definecolor{secondyellow}{HTML}{F4D03F}
\definecolor{thirdorange}{HTML}{F39C12} 
\definecolor{purple1}{HTML}{D7BDE2}
\definecolor{purple2}{HTML}{BB8FCE} 
\definecolor{purple3}{HTML}{A569BD}
\definecolor{purple4}{HTML}{884EA0} 
\definecolor{root}{HTML}{B2B2B2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta,calc,shadows.blur,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
\def\arctext[#1][#2][#3](#4)(#5)(#6)#7{

\draw[
color=white,
thick,
line width=1.3pt,
fill=#2
]
(#5:#4cm+#3) coordinate (above #1) arc (#5:#6:#4cm+#3)
-- (#6:#4) coordinate (right #1) -- (#6:#4cm-#3) coordinate (below right #1) 
arc (#6:#5:#4cm-#3) coordinate (below #1)
-- (#5:#4) coordinate (left #1) -- cycle;
\def\a#1{#4cm+#3}
\def\b#1{#4cm-#3}
\path[
decoration={
    raise = -0.5ex, % Controls relavite text height position.
    text  along path,
    text = {#7},
    text align = center,        
},
decorate
]
(#5:#4) arc (#5:#6:#4);
}

%arcarrow, this is mine, for beerware purpose...
%Function: Draw an arrow from arctex coordinate specific nodes to another 
%Arrow start at the start of arctext box and could be shifted to change the position
%to avoid go over another box.
%Var: 1:Start coordinate 2:End coordinate 3:angle to shift from acrtext box  
\def\arcarrow[#1](#2)(#3)[#4]{
\draw[thick,-,>=latex,color=#1,line width=1pt,shorten >=-2pt, shorten <=-2pt] 
    let \p1 = (#2), \p2 = (#3), % To access cartesian coordinates x, and y.
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}, % Distance from the origin
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}, % Distance from the origin
        \n3 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)} % Angle where acrtext starts.
    in (\n3-#4: \n1) -- (\n3-#4: \n2); % Draw the arrow.
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    Center/.style ={
        circle,
        fill=white,
        text=root,
        align=center,
        font =\footnotesize,
        inner sep=1pt,
    },
]
% Drawing the center
\node[Center](ROOT) at (0,0) {E};
% Drawing the Tex Arcs
% \Arctext[ID][box-style][box-height](radius)(start-angl)(end-angl){|text-styles| Text}
% Inner ring.
\arctext[N1][firstgreen][15pt](1.5)(90)(-3.6){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| 1 26};
\arctext[N2][secondyellow][10pt](1.5)(147.6)(356.4){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| 2 58};
\arctext[N3][thirdorange][15pt](1.5)(147.6)(90){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| 3 16};
% Outer ring
\arctext[N1S1][purple1][13pt](2.5)(90)(-3.6){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| Sub1};
\arctext[N2S4][purple4][13pt](2.5)(147.6)(356.4){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| Sub2};
\arctext[N3S1][purple1][13pt](2.5)(147.6)(90){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| Sub3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{2cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    Center/.style ={
        circle,
        fill=white,
        text=root,
        align=center,
        font =\footnotesize,
        inner sep=1pt,
    },
]
% Drawing the center
\node[Center](ROOT) at (0,0) {V};
% Drawing the Tex Arcs
% \Arctext[ID][box-style][box-height](radius)(start-angl)(end-angl){|text-styles| Text}
% Inner ring.
\arctext[N1][firstgreen][10pt](1.5)(90)(-68.4){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| 1 44};
\arctext[N2][secondyellow][15pt](1.5)(194.4)(291.6){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| 2 27};
\arctext[N3][thirdorange][15pt](1.5)(194.4)(90){|\footnotesize\bf\color{white}| 3 29};
% Outer ring
% 1
\arctext[N1S1][purple1][13pt](2.5)(90)(-49.4){};
\arctext[N1S2][purple2][13pt](2.5)(310.6)(307.4){};
\arctext[N1S3][purple3][13pt](2.5)(307.4)(293.2){};
\arctext[N1S4][purple4][13pt](2.5)(293.2)(291.6){};
% 2
\arctext[N2S1][purple1][13pt](2.5)(291.6)(252.7){};
\arctext[N2S2][purple2][13pt](2.5)(252.7)(223.6){};
\arctext[N2S3][purple3][13pt](2.5)(223.6)(215.8){};
\arctext[N2S4][purple4][13pt](2.5)(215.8)(194.4){};
% 3
\arctext[N3S1][purple1][13pt](2.5)(194.4)(175.6){};
\arctext[N3S2][purple2][13pt](2.5)(175.6)(103.6){};
\arctext[N3S3][purple3][13pt](2.5)(103.6)(90){};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{CAPTION}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Macros need to be inside additional braces and surrounded by text (blanks will do}.  `text={ {\%} }`

Comment: What sort of legend? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture/148855?r=SearchResults&s=4|31.1059#148855

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The text in the arcs is given to the key `arc data`. The direction of this text depends on the angle of the middle of the arc given by `\WCmidangle` which is used in the key `arc data dir`. The position of this text is determined by the key `arc data pos`.

The gaps between the slices are obtained with the key `gap`.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{firstgreen}{HTML}{58D68D}
\definecolor{secondyellow}{HTML}{F4D03F}
\definecolor{thirdorange}{HTML}{F39C12}
\definecolor{purple1}{HTML}{D7BDE2}
\definecolor{purple2}{HTML}{BB8FCE}
\definecolor{purple3}{HTML}{A569BD}
\definecolor{purple4}{HTML}{884EA0}
\definecolor{root}{HTML}{B2B2B2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?1:-1},
  arc data pos=0.5,
  arc data style={text color=white},
  data=,
  gap=0.65pt/1cm,
  middle style={root,font=\footnotesize}
}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=|\footnotesize\bfseries|\WCvarC{} \WCpercentage{\,}{\%},
  middle=E,
  radius={1.5-\WCvarD pt/1cm}{1.5+\WCvarD pt/1cm}
]{%
  26/firstgreen/1/14.35,
  58/secondyellow/2/9.35,
  16/thirdorange/3/14.35%
}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=|\footnotesize\bfseries|\WCvarC,
  radius={2.5-12.35pt/1cm}{2.5+12.35pt/1cm}
]{%
  26/purple1/Sub1,
  58/purple4/Sub2,
  16/purple1/Sub3%
}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-7)}]
\wheelchart[
  arc data=|\footnotesize\bfseries|\WCvarC{} \WCpercentage{\,}{\%},
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WCvarB] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarC & \WCperc},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,-4) {%
      \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \WClegend
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  },
  middle=V,
  radius={1.5-\WCvarD pt/1cm}{1.5+\WCvarD pt/1cm}
]{%
  44/firstgreen/1/9.35,
  27/secondyellow/2/14.35,
  29/thirdorange/3/14.35%
}
\wheelchart[
  radius={2.5-12.35pt/1cm}{2.5+12.35pt/1cm}
]{%
  39/purple1,
  0.8/purple2,
  3.9/purple3,
  0.44/purple4,
  10.8/purple1,
  8.08/purple2,
  2.1/purple3,
  5.9/purple4,
  5.2/purple1,
  20/purple2,
  3.78/purple3%
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```