# How do I create a donut (or ring) chart in Overleaf?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Donut chart]

How do I create a chart similar to the one below. I want to be able to customize the percentages of each section & the text needs to appear inside.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! - Have a look at this site, i'm sure you will find a lot of related example. - For example [Resources (or instructions) on how to make a variable size donut/pie chart with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247878/124842). - A good question should contain a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Otherwise it sound like "Do-my-work-for-me."

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie

Comment: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301200/121799) is another example. (@HenriMenke To the best of my knowledge `pgf-pie` does not produce donut charts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! This is an almost exact copy of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301200/121799) with two modifications:

1. Use backgrounds to allow the labels to run out of the segments without being cut.
2. Use of pgfkeys in order to allow for a more straightforward adjustment of the parameters (radii and text color at the moment).

Result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfkeys{/donut/.cd,
inner radius/.initial=0.7cm,
inner radius=0.7cm,
outer radius/.initial=3.14cm,
outer radius=3.14cm,
text color/.initial=white,
text color=white}
\newcommand{\donutchart}[2][]{
   % Calculate total
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
   \foreach [count=\n] \value/\colour/\name in {#2} {
     \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
     \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
     \xdef\numitems{\n}
   }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/outer
  radius}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/inner radius}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/outer radius}
  +\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/inner radius})/2}

  \begin{scope}[#1]

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
    \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#2} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
          \filldraw[draw=white,fill=\colour]
          (-\cumnum:\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/outer radius}) 
          arc(-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/outer radius}) --
          (-\newcumnum:\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/inner radius}) 
          arc(-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/inner radius}) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
        \draw node [text=\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/text color}, 
        font=\bfseries\sffamily] at 
        (\midangle:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/donut/inner radius}+\wheelwidth/2}) {\name};

        \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
    }

  \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

 \donutchart[rotate=45]{15/blue/R,15/green/minitab, 15/red/arena, 15/orange/matlab,
 10/teal/capitaline, 10/violet/MS office, 20/purple/{C/C++},
 7/cyan/Java,7/gray/Python,25/yellow/mySQL}

 \donutchart[rotate=45,/donut/outer radius=4cm,/donut/inner radius=1cm,
 /donut/text color=black]{15/blue/R,15/green/minitab, 15/red/arena, 15/orange/matlab,
 10/teal/capitaline, 10/violet/MS office, 20/purple/{C/C++},
 7/cyan/Java,7/gray/Python,25/yellow/mySQL}

\end{document}
```

[image]